# Python Exe file execution error

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```

I've saved this as a new .py file, then converted it into an .exe using py2exe.

When testing this code on another machine it does not execute as intended, am I missing a step, or is there an error in my code?

Comment: Do you see some kind of error message? Please explain what does not work as expected.

Comment: it should open google.com page on the default browser but just command prompt appear and goes away